# react-native-vlc-media-player cannot run on Android

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, sass

I installed the lib to watch the camera rtsp stream on react native app, the IOS worked fine without any settings, but android version kept
Can't load vlcjni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__sfp_handle_exceptions" referenced by ".

Any suggestions on this?

Install the library and then use the VlCPlayer to handle the stream view

Comment: You can consult: https://github.com/razorRun/react-native-vlc-media-player/issues/158#issuecomment-1527236194